# How to make the sculpt detail size always look the same?

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting, dynamic-topology

I've been sculpting using the *dynamic topology*. Set the ***detail size*** in the *Dynotopo* panel. When I zoom out of the object and sculpt, the detail size is appearing bigger. Is there a way to make the detail size look the same no matter how far the view from the object is?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to switch to Constant Detail in the Dynotopo panel.

[image: constant detail]